# Is there a good way to set available countries in Drupal Commerce shipping and billing?

Tags: commerce

On `admin/commerce/customer-profiles/types/billing/fields/commerce_customer_address` and
`admin/commerce/customer-profiles/types/shipping/fields/commerce_customer_address` one is supposed to select the available countries in a little box. This is not ideal. So I would like to do this programmatically (possibly with `drush`), is there already a quick solution for this or do I have to delve into this myself?

[image: this is the little box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you mean by 'quick', really. Yes, you can do it programatically. With PHP:

```
$instance_config = field_info_instance('commerce_customer_profile', 'commerce_customer_address', 'shipping');

$instance_config['widget']['settings']['available_countries'] = array(
  'GB',
  'US',
  'FR',
  // etc...
);

field_update_instance($instance_config);
```

Or with JS (I'll let you work that one out, selecting a bunch of `<option>` tags based on a bunch of values is very easy).

IMO the time-consuming part is building up the array of default countries in the first place; no matter what automated method you use to put the values in, someone needs to spend the time choosing and preparing them. You can't get away from that.

Comment: This is going in the right direction. Where can I put this PHP code?

Comment: Depends - where do you need to run it?

Comment: You can get the code of the array from the webform module (I know it's there because it gives you the option to populate a select box with countries)

Comment: I ran it through `drush php-script`, still needed to open the form and save it before it works, before doing that the list of countries was empty at checkout. The list was the list of EU countries, pretty straightforward stuff (:

Answer (score 0):

When being confronted with large lists in a small field, I normally pull up the developer tools of the browser, find the appropriate `select`-element and manually assign a suitable attribute (e.g. `height=800px`). Like this it is much easier to choose ranges of entries without loosing oversight.

[image]